# How set max partitions for Hive query in ipython notebook

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a script currently using Ipython notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyhs2
import os
import datetime

q1= "set hive.query.max.partition = 3000 ; 
select 'Device_id' as key,
'All Time' as type,
count(distinct a.dev_id) as count
from (select distinct dev_id from DevID
where dev_type = '*****' 
union all 
    select distinct
    key_value_lookup(raw_url, '*****',  '&', '=') as dev_id
    from actions 
    where raw_url like '%*****%'
    and raw_url like '%*****%' 
    and data_date >= '20150901' and data_date <= '20151231') a"

def read_hive(query):
conn = pyhs2.connect(host='*****',
                   port=*****,
                   authMechanism="*****",
                   user='*****',
                   password='*****',
                   database='*****')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
    #Return column info from query
if cur.getSchema() is None:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return Nonea

columnNames = [a['columnName'] for a in  cur.getSchema()] 
print columnNames
columnNamesStrings = [a['columnName'] for a in  cur.getSchema() if a['type']=='STRING_TYPE'] 
output =  pd.DataFrame(cur.fetch(),columns=columnNames)   

cur.close()
conn.close()
return output
```

When calling `read_hive(q1)`, I receive the following error:

> FAILED because hive.query.max.partition expects an INT value

I believe that this is because I am storing the query in a string, but am not completely sure. The query runs perfectly well from Hue.

Does anyone have intuition into the best way to change the maximum amount of partitions? Can this be done in my function?

Answer (score 0):

Hive configuration settings should be passed as a dictionary to the pyhs2 Connection object - not as part of the query string to execute.

In your case:

```
conn = pyhs2.connect(host='*****',
               port=*****,
               authMechanism="*****",
               user='*****',
               password='*****',
               database='*****',
               configuration={'hive.query.max.partition': '3000'})
```